# Preserve order in wordpress query

Tags: sql, wordpress

I'm makign one wordpress theme where I want to show more pages on home page. I made `home.php` which starts with this:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'page',
  'post__in' => explode(",",get_option('fp_pages')));
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ): $the_query->the_post(); 
....
```

I have one big problem. `fp_pages` has page ids divided with commas. I want them than to show on page in that order but result is different. Order of IDs doesn't matter - they are always the same, but I want it as I wrote it in `fp_pages`.

I did some research on web and found `FIND_IN_SET()`. My problem is that I don't know how to integrate it in wordpress query. Another possibility is to load them from database one by one but I'm afraid that it can slow down page loading (I'm talking about 8 - 10 pages max).

So can you help me with integrating `FIND_IN_SET()` to wordpress query or maybe tell if loading one by one is good idea or tell another solution :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have a look at the [Order & Orderby Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) of [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). Since Wordpress 3.5, you have the option to preserve the order of posts by ID given in `post__in`

> **'post__in'** - Preserve post ID order given in the `post__in` array (available with Version 3.5).

So you can simply add `'orderby' => 'post__in',` to your query arguments